# Problems when i'm using qsort for double

Tags: c, qsort

My english is very poor,so if there is any mistake please forgive me. Thank you !

i have this problem when i using qsort to sort this struct:

```
    typedef struct 
{
    double cost,earn;
}ac;
```

i want to sort it like this:

```
int cmp(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    ac this_a=*(ac*)a;
    ac this_b=*(ac*)b;
    return (this_b.earn/this_b.cost-this_a.earn/this_a.cost)>0.0;
}
```

but it didn't work. when i changed to this,it worked:

```
int cmp(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    ac this_a=*(ac*)a;
    ac this_b=*(ac*)b;
    return (this_a.cost*this_b.earn-this_a.earn*this_b.cost);
}
```

Why this happend?IS there Any different between the two function? Or maybe the other part of the code is wrong?

Comment: remove `>0.0` on the first example and it'll run just fine

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: The difference betwween the two is not limited to that `> 0.0`.  The change made to the formula in the second case was obviously made to avoid "division by zero" problem. Apparently, this was an issue as well. So, removal of `>0.0` in the first case is apparently not sufficient.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yes, you're right, the second one not also remove the problem but also improve performance

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: The performance might be better, but the second one is still broken: it suffers from overflow problem.

Comment: Thank you all. In fact, the inputs are small num, so it won't suffer from overflow problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compare function must return an integer less than zero, equal to zero or greater than zero depending on how you want the two items sorted.

In your first example, you return the result of an > operation. This is 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you. So,when i want to sort fractions things i should not sort it directly but change it to a subtraction stuff. (my english is so poor……)

Comment: The second version also has problems: It returns zero incorrectly when the result of the subtraction is non-zero but less than one in magnitude, and, in other cases, the conversion to `int` may overflow.

Answer (score 1):

As you can easily see yourself, there is a difference between the two functions. The first one contains `> 0.0` at the end in the expression in `return` statement. (Also, the first one uses division while the second one uses multiplication. However, if the values are non-negative, the transformation applied to the formula actually performs an equivalent comparison without suffering from the danger of division by zero.)

Note that neither implementation is good. The first one does not even remotely do what a tri-state comparison function for `qsort` is supposed to do, as you already noticed. The second one might work correctly as long as the `double` values are relatively small. But as these values get larger, the conversion from `double` to `int` might begin to overflow, causing undefined behavior.

So, don't ever use direct subtraction for generating the tri-state comparison result (except for, maybe, types smaller than `int`). If you need to compare two values, say, `a` and `b`, use the `return (a > b) - (a < b)` idiom. This is how it might look in your case

```
double lhs = this_a.cost * this_b.earn;
double rhs = this_a.earn * this_b.cost;
return (lhs > rhs) - (lhs < rhs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first function will only ever return 0 or 1.

The second function will return "negative number", 0, or "positive number" which is probably what you want to represent "less than", "equal", and "greater than"